# Creating dictionary of dictionaries in python 2.6

Tags: python, python-2.7, list-comprehension, python-2.6

I have a line of code in python2.7 that generates a dictionary of empty dictionaries:

```
values=[0,1,2,4,5,8] 
value_dicts={x:{} for x in values}
```

which throws a syntax error when run on python2.6.

I can do the same thing using a for loop:

```
values_dicts={}
values=[0,1,2,4,5,8]
for value in values :
values_dicts[value]={}
values_dicts
Out[25]: {0: {}, 1: {}, 2: {}, 4: {}, 5: {}, 8: {}}
```

But that seems silly. Why does the list comprehension (in the first block) not work in python2.6?

Comment: Aside: that's not a list comprehension, it's a dictionary comprehension, which was only introduced in 2.7/3.0 (see [PEP 274](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0274/) for the history).  As for why they haven't always existed, to preserve the integrity of the space-time continuum, Guido tries to limit use of his [time machine](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/G/Guido.html).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use the `dict()` constructor:

```
value_dicts = dict((x, {}) for x in values)
```

This uses a generator expression that constructs `(key, value)` tuples, which the `dict()` constructor is happy to turn into a dictionary for you.

Demo:

```
>>> values=[0,1,2,4,5,8] 
>>> dict((x, {}) for x in values)
{0: {}, 1: {}, 2: {}, 4: {}, 5: {}, 8: {}}
```

The syntax you used (a dict comprehension) was not introduced until Python 2.7 and Python 3, see [PEP 274](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0274/).

Comment: Thank you - this will do nicely, and thanks for pointing out the distinction between list and dict comprehension.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your intended use, you could also just use a defaultdict instead.

```
from collections import defaultdict
value_dicts = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(int))
```